# PHP remote login to mysql db: "cannot select db"

Tags: php, mysql

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');


$host="host.org"; // Host name 
$username="myServer_guest"; // Mysql username 
$password="password"; // Mysql password 
$db_name="myServer_JMblog"; // Database name 
$tbl_name="blog"; // Table name

// Connect to server and select databse.
$link=mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
echo $link.'<br>';


mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");
?>
```

I am getting a successful connection, but now I cannot select the db. All login credentials are correct. Any help would be amazing.

Comment: Any errors? Does the user have access to the db you wish to access?

Comment: @jason even though you are assuring to have a successful connection... what port is the server allowing you in? Are you sure you're really habing a good connection? What is `skip-networking` commented out on `my.cfg` ?

Comment: i am asking for connection on 3306. where would i find my `my.cfg`?

Comment: Instead of your fixed-message die()s, try doing `die(mysql_error())` instead, to get some more useful debug output. For all you know the DB's perfectly fine but the user/host you're connecting as have no rights to access it.

Comment: probably you should check your users table, too.

Comment: marc B, thanks this pointed out something I was unaware of. my web host is digging into this. they seem to have a bunch of firewalls etc set up such that site1 cannot without permission access site2. they are looking into it. i will post a full conclusion to this once it is cleared up.

Comment: marc B, please add this as an answer so i can give you credit. problem is solved. once you answer i will add some details as a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

issue was adding not only remote access for site "abc.com" but also adding the remote site IP. Once this was completed it worked! Thank you Marc B for the great pointers.

Answer (score 0):

Good sugegstions in comments already.
Another thing to understand is that credentials can be different
from differnt boxes. A easy test is to try simple login using mysql-shell directly,
preferably if possible from same machin/IP as the php is running on.

Try cmd> mysql -hhost.org -umyServer_guest -ppassword Server_JMblog

You will probably get an error since your php isn't working,
post this error and it can tell you more on teh actual problem.